# Security token not needed for clients when accessing 3rd party apps?

Tags: security

We have a client facing app that we've developed.  Our users can login to the app without providing a security key, only a client user login.  Yet the app does interface and update data in our Salesforce org.  Normally when we are using 3rd party apps we are required to login with a security token.  Why is this NOT required for client logins?

Comment: how is the authentication between the app and Salesforce is happening? Are you passing the username and pwd and trying to get a session?

Comment: Yes 'client' users login with a username and PW.

Comment: Keep in mind security token is used as a second factor authentication for API calls ... 2FA for user interface are email verification or other methods not token

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your client application is authenticating with Salesforce.

If it is a connected app using something like the [Web Server](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_an_Access_Token_in_a_Web_Application_.28Web_Server_Flow.29) flow then it doesn't require the security token.

Like wise if the clients IP address is listed in the Trusted Networks or they have explicit Restricted IP ranges.